# ways to convert chm to djvu

Tags: djvu, chm

I was wondering how to convert chm to djvu?  Command line, GUI or online solutions are both fine. My OS is 10.10.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to convert the chm file through an intermediary file format such as PDF.

Two packages are available in synaptic manager/software center, `pdf2djvu` and `chm2pdf`

Suggested conversion syntax for an example.chm file:

```
chm2pdf --book example.chm
pdf2djvu -o example.djvu example.pdf
```

Comment: chm2pdf cannot start if the chm-filename contains parentheses (and other funny characters). Renaming the file helps.